# How to use Max while taking other values from another column?

Tags: sql

I am new in SQL and have problem picking the biggest value of a column for every manager_id and also other information in the same row.

Let me show the example - consider this table:

| name | manager_id | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 100 |
| David | 1 | 80 |
| Selena | 2 | 26 |
| Leo | 1 | 120 |
| Frank | 2 | 97 |
| Sara | 2 | 105 |

and the result I am expecting would be like this:

| name | manager_id | top_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Leo | 1 | 120 |
| Sara | 2 | 105 |

I tried using Max but the problem is that I must group it with `manager_id` and not being able to take name of the `salesPerson`.

```
select manager_id, max(sales) as top_sales 
from table 
group by manager_id ;
```

This is just an example and the actual query is very long and I am taking the information from different tables. I know that I can use the same table and join it again but the problem is as I mentioned this query is very long as I am extracting info from different tables with multiple conditions. And I don't want to make a temporary table to save it. It should be done in one single query and I actually did solve this but the query is super long due to the inner join that I used and made original table twice.

My question is that can I use Max and have the value in the name column or is there other method to solve this?

Appreciate all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row_number() with CTE to get the highest sales for each manager as below:

```
with MaxSales as (
select name, manager_id, sales,row_number() over (partition by manager_id order by sales desc) rownumber from table 
)
select name , manager_id ,sales from MaxSales  where rownumber=1
```

Comment: My Pleasure. Thanks for accepting my answer. Best wishes.